# Regular Expression: Get file extension from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a link (string)  which contains a filename. I need to extract the format of the filename but I am unfortunately not able to do that. An example link is given below

> www.xyz.com/private/videos/89FDJKDKFgrFTD-MUyKE9Sn/source?file-name=SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3&**token**=exp=1591202847~acl=/private/videos/8OJFREFJOIJFREJ-MUyKE9Sn/source*~hmac=aef161514cdfodsjfodsjorjef081b4c849b8c29c6a37339803866badfd4a16

I have tried multiple ways like to look for **.(dot)** until **&** but since I am new to this I couldn't make this work. I got the filename through `name=([^&]*)` but could not get the extension. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:file-name=.*)(\..+)(?:&)
```

Also see working example: https://regex101.com/r/CJDXLW/2

Comment: I just need the extension. This gives the complete filename

Comment: I updated the answer check it again please.

Comment: Works now. Thanks

Comment: Np :) Accepted answer will be appreciated.